# Tablea: Adding Grand Total

Tags: tableau-api

I added a grand total on my tableau report that should sum the surveys, average the Composite, Satisfaction and Resolution, but the grand total is blank.

[image]

Comment: Hard to help when we have no clue what the data you're using look like, nor what aggregation each column is using. Sending a .twbx would be very helpful

Comment: The column Survey is a SUM, the rest of the columns are AVERAGE.

Comment: Tableau is not meant to be used as a replacement for Excel and is not the best tabular data tool.  Unfortunately, you can not SUM headers like you are attempting (discrete measures I assume), tableau subtotal and grand total functionality applies to continuous measures (sometimes discrete) that are in in the text field or row/column shelf.